# C# Key Press; display key in Label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, keydown

I have a form (`Form1`) and a label (`lblTest`)

What code do I need to insert so when any key is pressed, the key is displayed in the label? This event should take place when the form is selected

E.g. if the user presses <kbd>g</kbd>, a `g` is displayed in the label.

I have tried some code in the `Form_KeyDown` event, but I can't get it to work.

I'm currently looking at [this](http://www.csharpcorner.com/UploadFile/grusso/KeyLoggerAplicationinCSharp11252005000941AM/KeyLoggerAplicationinCSharp.aspx).

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: stuff like lblTest.text == [code]; this has been a range of things, still trying

Comment: Nice joke...add whole code in question please.

Comment: Have you proved that your KeyDown event code is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
...
myForm.KeyPreview = true;
...

private void CommsTesterUI_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
form1.KeyPreview = true;
```

(or set in the designer)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code if you need to build a string:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    lblControl.Text += (char) e.KeyCode;
}
```

else, if you need to show only  the button pressed:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    lblControl.Text = ((char) e.KeyCode).ToString();
}
```

Obiosly, the focus must be on the form.